# Persistent UIBarButtonItem on all navigation bars within tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Ok so I have a tabbar iPhone application. The tabbarcontroller contains about 5 view controllers that are each embedded in their own navigation controller with the exception of 1 in which I just added a navigation bar in IB for a consistent look throughout the app. On every navigation bar in the app, I want a rightBarButtonItem that will open up the same modal view controller no matter where it is selected from. Similar to the "Now Playing" button in the music app, I want the button to stay on every navigation bar regardless of which tab I'm on or how deep I navigate into a navigation controller. How would I go about doing something like this? Is there some way I could simply apply the button to every nav bar in the same way UIAppearance can apply an image to every nav bar in an app? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to create a base view controller from which all your other view controllers extend.

With this in place, you could set up a `UIBarButtonItem` in the `viewDidLoad` method that attaches itself to the navigation bar and listens for events. From there, it would be quite easy to observe events and present either a modal view controller or push the appropriate view controller on to the navigation stack.

I use this approach for a "logout" bar button item that presents the login view controller when tapped as a quick alternative for users to sign out of their account.

The only down side to this is that each and every view controller that inherits from the base view controller will have the logout button in the navigation bar. Should you need other buttons or want to hide the default button, you need to replace it with another button instead.

It's a quick and easy approach and is also quite simple to remove if required as you can just change the header file to reflect the inheritance rather than sifting through several view controllers removing every instance of the button. It's also easy to maintain as you could overload the button target in any subclasses to perform different functionality when the event is fired.